# How to execute unicode .sql file on azure sql via sqlcmd?

Tags: azure, sql-server

I have an Azure blog created via "Brandoo WordPress" template (wordpress website and azure sql server). All works fine, but if I populate wordpress tables from .sql file with unicode characters via `sqlcmd` command I see "?" on website instead of non-english letters. Using wordpress interface I can add new posts with non-english letters, so it's not a database problem.

I have tried many combination of file encoding (utf-8, utf-8 with bom, utf-16, utf-16 with bom) and `-f` `sqlcmd` command-line key that suppose to force it into unicode, for example:

```
sqlcmd -S foo.database.windows.net -d bar -U user -P pass -f 65001 -i db.sql
```

Unfortunately, nothing works, I always see `?` instead of non-english characters on website. Is it any way to sole this problem, or azure and `sqlcmd` are not intended to be used together with non-english characters?

Comment: Is it possible the ? characters are an issue with the browser vs at the server level? Perhaps you could grab a Fiddler trace of the HTTP request and see what the server is actually sending over the wire?

Comment: @proteus Server actually sends utf-8 '?' characters. If I add some articles using wordpress web interface, non-english characters can be used, so it's definitely not a database or server itself.